# QStackedLayout implicitly shows added widget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Considering the simple application

```
#include <QtWidgets>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QStackedLayout stack;
    stack.addWidget(new QLabel("Calls QLabel::show()?"));
    return app.exec();
}
```

with qmake project

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = main
QT += widgets
CONFIG += c++11
SOURCES += main.cpp
```

one would intuitionally expect an application without any UI, since `QWidget::show` was not called on any widget. However the added label will be shown, which leads to the assumption, that [`QStackedLayout::addWidget`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedlayout.html#addWidget) shows this widget, which might cohere with:

> If the `QStackedLayout` is empty before this function is called, the given widget becomes the current widget.

Is this supposed to work that way? How do I get rid of this counterintuitive behaviour? It is the only layout I found working that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this supposed to work that way?

I suspect that the author of the QStackedLayout class never considered the possibility of somebody putting a top-level-widget into the layout.  That seems like an odd thing to want to do.

Regarding intent:  without talking to the author, though, the best we can do is look at the code inside qstackedlayout.cpp.  I see that QStackedLayout::addWidget() calls QStackedLayout::insertWidget(), which calls QStackedLayout::setCurrentIndex(), which calls show() on the widget; that would explain why your QLabel becomes visible.

> How do I get rid of this counterintuitive behaviour?

Typically in a Qt program, you don't addChild() your top-level widget to a layout.  Instead, you'd create your own separate top level-widget, create a layout that is associated with it, and then add child widgets to the layout, like this:

```
QWidget topWidget;
QStackedLayout * stack = new QStackedLayout(&topWidget);
stack->addWidget(new QLabel("Calls QLabel::show()?"));
return app.exec();
```

Comment: This problem was part of more complex application, where the stacked widgets were shown in their own window, just before the main window was shown. I guess I shouldn't build the layout bottom up. I also found the `QStackedWidget`, which acts just like your example. Thank you.